# Loading text/ng-template in AngularJS directives correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that I want to clear the content of a DIV and replace it with a template either in my current view or somewhere else in my app.

So say I have my template like so...

```
<!-- This is an experiment -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="1.html">
     <div data-ng-repeat="beatle in beatles track by $index">
      Name: {{beatle.name}}, Instrument: {{ beatle.inst}}, Alive: {{ beatle.alive }}
    </div>
</script>
```

and in my directive I have the following:

```
link: function (scope, element) {
                element.bind('click', function () {

                    // clear out old template
                    angular.element(element).empty();
                    angular.element(element).html(document.getElementById('1.html'));

                });
            }
```

I seem to be able to load the template but I see the following instead of my content

```
[object HTMLScriptElement]
```

I wondering if I need to compile again or run a digest or if I am just going about this totally wrong. I also don't like using  `document.getElementById` in my directive code, for some reason it feels wrong. Can anyone provide me with an answer to why I only see `[object HTMLScriptElement]` after clicking my directive and wether using `document.getElementById` in my directive is acceptable or if there is a better command to load the content...

Here is a fiddle of the whole app... or a bin! https://jsbin.com/yizupa/edit?html,output

Comment: Do you only want the replacement to happen when you click? Normally you would a directive like this: https://jsbin.com/qudategoda/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Hi, Pretty much yeah, I am more concerned with loading the template into the div that anything else. My original directive will cover large areas of the interface, I can't use the template directive or the templateUrl in my current implementation. I just want to load the new content into the container...

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I have just came to the conclusion that my setup / implementation is wrong and that I should consider another way to implement such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
here, i have create one running demo.. for route using **text/ng-template**..

index.html
-------------

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="singlePageApp">
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS Routing Template..</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="singlePageAppController">
{{message}}
</div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
<div ng-view="showOutput"></div>
</body>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
           This is HOME Page..
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="about.html">
           This is ABOUT Page..
    </script>


</html>

--------
app.js
--------

var app=angular.module('singlePageApp',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when('/home',{
            controller:'singlePageAppController',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })
        .when('/about',{
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
        });

});

app.controller('singlePageAppController',function($scope){

    $scope.message="Hello Single Page Application..";

});
```